# Pass new object or object reference

Tags: c#, object, constructor, reference, asp.net-mvc-5

In C#, (expressly MVC 5), should I just pass a new object to a constructor or a reference to an object that has already been created?

Here is the code that I am referring to:

1.

```
TestDatabaseContext db = new TestDatabaseContext();
testObject = new TestObject(db);
```

or

2.

```
testObject = new TestObject(new TestDatabaseContext());
```

Do the two above examples of code achieve the same result? Should I favor one approach over the other?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference at all.

1) Good if you need to add some properties to db before passing it to TestObject.

2) You can do the same as I mentioned in #1 using Object Initializer

```
testObject = new TestObject(new TestDatabaseContext{id=1, otherproperty=whatever});
```

Same thing, no difference

You'll just want to do it whichever way your development team prefers I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same..

If you want to assign any `property` or `member` before passing it to the function then you can use `1` to keep the code neat and clean. However you can also do the same by the approach suggested by @prospector.

Answer (score 0):

It DOES make difference if

`TestDatabaseContext db = new TestDatabaseContext();`

is not in the same codeblock (Method) than

`testObject = new TestObject(db);`

With 1, you will use the same `db` instance again (e.g. if it is set in the constructor and you set the `testObject` variable in a method), with 2, every time you set `testObject`, a new instance of `TestDatabaseContext` will be used.

Its up to you if you want to reuse the `db` instance, if the two lines are in the same method/constructor/... it does not make any difference otherwise it does.